# json encode not working in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Im trying to send an array from PHP to Javascript using AJAX. The array consists of fields retrieved from a database.
I tried using JSON_encode for sending the array but it returns a null value. I read up on the internet and found the problem to be the content-type. The content type has to be set to text/JSON.
However i am already using text/XML in the php code which i assume is necessary for AJAX call in javascript.(I tried replacing text/xml by text/json but then the xmlhttpObject became null)
Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';
echo '<response>';
require 'connect.inc.php';
$sub=$_GET['sub'];
$no=$_GET['no'];

$query="SELECT * FROM ".$sub." WHERE id='".$no."'";


if($query_run=mysql_query($query)) {
    if($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
        $ques=$query_row['question'];
        $op1=$query_row['op1'];
        $op2=$query_row['op2'];
        $op3=$query_row['op3'];
        $op4=$query_row['op4'];
        $ans=$query_row['ans'];
        $result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM ".$sub);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $total = $row[0];
        $array=array($ques,$op1,$op2,$op3,$op4,$ans,$total,$id);


        echo json_encode($array);
    }
} else {
    echo mysql_error();
}       
echo'</response>';
?>
```

And here is the javascript snippet which handles the server response:

```
    function handleServerResponse() {
    if (xmlHttp1.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlHttp1.status == 200) {
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp1.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            array = JSON.parse(message);
            document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = array[0];
            document.getElementById('option1').innerHTML = array[1];
            document.getElementById('option2').innerHTML = array[2];
            document.getElementById('option3').innerHTML = array[3];
            document.getElementById('option4').innerHTML = array[4];
            answerArray[qno] = array[5];
            noOfQuest = array[6];
        }
        else {
            alert('Something went wrong!');
        }
    }
}
```

array=JSON.parse(message) returns null. I think that is because message is null.
How do I solve this problem?

Thanks a lot

Update: I checked 'message', it says undefined.
I also tried to send a single value from php to js without json encode, it still gives undefined

Comment: And what is in the `message` variable?

Comment: Im sorry actually the message variable returns null...I will update the question
Is there some line i have left out?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only json output as result, you have to change some lines in your php file like

(**See last five lines**):

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';
echo '<response>';
require 'connect.inc.php';
$sub=$_GET['sub'];
$no=$_GET['no'];

$query="SELECT * FROM ".$sub." WHERE id='".$no."'";


if($query_run=mysql_query($query)) {
    if($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
        $ques=$query_row['question'];
        $op1=$query_row['op1'];
        $op2=$query_row['op2'];
        $op3=$query_row['op3'];
        $op4=$query_row['op4'];
        $ans=$query_row['ans'];
        $result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM ".$sub);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $total = $row[0];
        $array=array($ques,$op1,$op2,$op3,$op4,$ans,$total,$id);
    }
} else {
     $array = array('result' => 'error', 'message' => mysql_error());
}
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The *X* in AJAX is very deceptive, "AJAX" requests don't have to use XML; in fact almost no modern code use XML for AJAX today.

XML and JSON are two different data exchange formats. Encode it as either one or the other. JSON would be best since it is super easy to both read and write in JavaScript and most other languages.

Strip out all the XML stuff in the PHP, send as `application/json` and use `responseText` to retrieve it instead of `responseXML`.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

require 'connect.inc.php';
$sub=$_GET['sub'];
$no=$_GET['no'];

// VERY IMPORTANT, escape all uses provided data before using it in a query!!!
$sub=mysql_real_escape_string($sub);
$no=mysql_real_escape_string($no);

$query="SELECT * FROM ".$sub." WHERE id='".$no."'";

if($query_run=mysql_query($query)) {
    if($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
        $ques=$query_row['question'];
        $op1=$query_row['op1'];
        $op2=$query_row['op2'];
        $op3=$query_row['op3'];
        $op4=$query_row['op4'];
        $ans=$query_row['ans'];
        $result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM ".$sub);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $total = $row[0];
        $array=array($ques,$op1,$op2,$op3,$op4,$ans,$total,$id);

        echo json_encode($array);
    }
} else {
    // send a 500 HTTP error code so the browser knows there was an error
    // when handling the AJAX.
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    echo mysql_error();
}       
?>
```

You'll notice I used [`mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape the user-provided data. Doing this is very important to avoid [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). It would be even better to switch to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and use it's ability to execute [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) to ensure unescaped user data isn't accidentally used in queries.

```
function handleServerResponse() {
  if (xmlHttp1.readyState == 4) {
      if (xmlHttp1.status == 200) {
          // make sure to declare your local variable with the var statement
          // or they will be implied globals!
          var json = xmlHttp1.responseText;
          var array = JSON.parse(json);
          document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = array[0];
          document.getElementById('option1').innerHTML = array[1];
          document.getElementById('option2').innerHTML = array[2];
          document.getElementById('option3').innerHTML = array[3];
          document.getElementById('option4').innerHTML = array[4];
          answerArray[qno] = array[5];
          noOfQuest = array[6];
      }
      else {
          alert('Something went wrong!');
      }
  }
}
```